# Ajax Error Unknown server tag 'asp:AutoCompleteExtender'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

Unknown server tag 'asp:AutoCompleteExtender'.
what should I do to use AutoCompleteExtender in MVC.
I have no problem with this when using in aspx page holding single textbox/ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what should i do to use AutoCompleteExtender

Nothing. You shouldn't use server side controls in an ASP.NET MVC application. I would recommend you taking a look at [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) and its [AutoComplete widget](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/).

Comment: yes Darin you are right this can be done by jquery also. But i want it to be done with AJax only

Comment: @dhiraj.Saini, as I said you cannot use server side controls in an ASP.NET MVC applications. You cannot and should not use the AjaxControlToolKit. It simply is not intended for ASP.NET MVC. If you want to use this framework you have to use classic WebForms, not ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: Oh Thanks Darin now i got your point (I am very new in development).But have a look  // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    // [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]

Comment: when i create new webService to use Ajax in my ASP.Net MVC then these line comes at some place in WebService.asmx code. What is it?

Comment: One thing more i used ajax autocomplete in the same asp.net app(that giving error)//but in other view within the same application ajax autocomplete works

Comment: How is this an answer to the question?

Comment: @UriKlar, this answer explains why the controls used by OP doesn't work (because classic are not supported in ASP.NET MVC) and it suggests alternatives such as jQuery UI. I wonder what kind of answer you expected more specifically?